# Heroku push failing with build errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have a node.js / reactjs / js applciation that I am trying to push to Heroku. I pushed using the proper commands

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push Heroku master
```

once I do that, it takes about 2 minutes, and shows all this stuff below:

```
Enumerating objects: 192, done.
Counting objects: 100% (192/192), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (179/179), done.
Writing objects: 100% (192/192), 617.12 KiB | 5.93 MiB/s, done.
Total 192 (delta 26), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  14.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 14.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 14.16.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.14.12
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules
remote:        
remote:        > protobufjs@6.10.2 postinstall /tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/protobufjs
remote:        > node scripts/postinstall
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > grpc@1.24.6 install /tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/grpc
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
remote:        
remote:        [grpc] Success: "/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" is installed via remote
remote:        
remote:        > protobufjs@6.10.2 postinstall /tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/google-proto-files/node_modules/protobufjs
remote:        > node scripts/postinstall
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > protobufjs@6.10.2 postinstall /tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs
remote:        > node scripts/postinstall
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > grpc@1.20.0 install /tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
remote:        
remote:        make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/build'
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/backoff/backoff.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack_builder.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_trace.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channelz.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channelz_registry.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/connected_channel.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/handshaker.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/handshaker_registry.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/status_util.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/compression.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/compression_internal.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/message_compress.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression_gzip.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/compression/stream_compression_identity.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/debug/stats_data.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/http/format_request.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/http/httpcli.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/http/parser.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/buffer_list.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/call_combiner.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/combiner.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/endpoint.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/endpoint_pair_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/endpoint_pair_uv.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/endpoint_pair_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/error.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll1_linux.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epollex_linux.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_poll_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/exec_ctx.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/executor.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/fork_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/fork_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/gethostname_fallback.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/gethostname_host_name_max.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/gethostname_sysconf.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/grpc_if_nametoindex_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/grpc_if_nametoindex_unsupported.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/internal_errqueue.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iocp_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr_custom.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr_internal.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr_uv.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/iomgr_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/is_epollexclusive_available.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/load_file.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/lockfree_event.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/polling_entity.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_custom.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_set.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_set_custom.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_set_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_uv.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/pollset_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address_custom.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/resource_quota.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/sockaddr_utils.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_factory_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_mutator.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_linux.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_uv.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_custom.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_client_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_custom.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/crypt/gsec.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/frame_protector/alts_counter.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/frame_protector/alts_crypter.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/frame_protector/alts_frame_protector.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/frame_protector/alts_record_protocol_crypter_common.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/frame_protector/alts_seal_privacy_integrity_crypter.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/frame_protector/alts_unseal_privacy_integrity_crypter.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/frame_protector/frame_handler.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_handshaker_client.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_shared_resource.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_tsi_handshaker.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/zero_copy_frame_protector/alts_grpc_integrity_only_record_protocol.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/zero_copy_frame_protector/alts_grpc_privacy_integrity_record_protocol.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/zero_copy_frame_protector/alts_grpc_record_protocol_common.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/zero_copy_frame_protector/alts_iovec_record_protocol.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/zero_copy_frame_protector/alts_zero_copy_grpc_protector.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/check_gcp_environment.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/check_gcp_environment_linux.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/check_gcp_environment_no_op.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/check_gcp_environment_windows.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/grpc_alts_credentials_client_options.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/grpc_alts_credentials_options.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/security/credentials/alts/grpc_alts_credentials_server_options.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_handshaker_service_api.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_handshaker_service_api_util.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/alts_tsi_utils.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/transport_security_common_api.o
remote:          CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/altscontext.pb.o
remote:          CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/handshaker.pb.o
remote:          CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/alts/handshaker/transport_security_common.pb.o
remote:          CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb_common.o
remote:          CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb_decode.o
remote:          CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb_encode.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/transport_security.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/insecure/channel_create.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/insecure/channel_create_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/authority.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/chttp2_connector.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/backup_poller.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/channel_connectivity.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel_channelz.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel_factory.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel_plugin.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/connector.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/global_subchannel_pool.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/health/health_check_client.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/http_connect_handshaker.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/http_proxy.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy_registry.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/local_subchannel_pool.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/parse_address.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/proxy_mapper.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/proxy_mapper_registry.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver_registry.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver_result_parsing.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolving_lb_policy.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/retry_throttle.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/server_address.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/service_config.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel_pool_interface.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/deadline/deadline_filter.o
remote:          CC(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/health/health.pb.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/fake_transport_security.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/local_transport_security.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl/session_cache/ssl_session_boringssl.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl/session_cache/ssl_session_cache.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl/session_cache/ssl_session_openssl.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/tsi/transport_security_grpc.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/chttp2_server.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/client/secure/secure_channel_create.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/insecure/server_chttp2.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/insecure/server_chttp2_posix.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/inproc/inproc_plugin.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/transport/inproc/inproc_transport.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/client_load_reporting_filter.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb_channel_secure.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/grpclb_client_stats.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/load_balancer_api.o
remote:        In file included from /usr/include/string.h:495,
remote:                         from ../deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb.h:68,
remote:                         from ../deps/grpc/third_party/nanopb/pb_decode.h:9,
remote:                         from ../deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/load_balancer_api.cc:21:
remote:        In function ‘char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)’,
remote:            inlined from ‘grpc_grpclb_request* grpc_grpclb_request_create(const char*)’ at ../deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/load_balancer_api.cc:70:10:
remote:        /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string_fortified.h:106:34: error: ‘char* __builtin_strncpy(char*, const char*, long unsigned int)’ specified bound 128 equals destination size [-Werror=stringop-truncation]
remote:          106 |   return __builtin___strncpy_chk (__dest, __src, __len, __bos (__dest));
remote:              |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:        cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
remote:        make: *** [grpc.target.mk:499: Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/grpclb/load_balancer_api.o] Error 1
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/build'
remote:        gyp ERR! build error 
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1088-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.1
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok 
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_1f7f74d3/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1088-aws
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.1
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
remote:        Failed to execute '/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/.heroku/node/bin/node /tmp/build_1f7f74d3/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=/tmp/build_1f7f74d3/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v83-linux-x64-glibc --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.2du46/_logs/2021-04-16T19_31_29_132Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to xxx.
```

I already uninstalled and reinstalled npm, as well as deleted package-lock.json, and node modules folder, then reinstalled with npm. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That error log shows that you are successfully installing grpc version 1.24.6, and failing to install grpc version 1.20.0. The problem is that grpc version 1.20.0 is not compatible with the version of Node that you are using. You will need to either use an older version of Node, or upgrade that dependency to a newer version of grpc.