# npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, heroku

when I push to Heroku using the standard commands, I get this error --- something to do with grpc:

```
    remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.yHnQ0/_logs/2021-04-16T20_01_23_896Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to cam
```

the main thing that I am seeing is this:

```
remote: npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
```

why would I be getting this?

Comment: Please share the first several lines of the error. That will help determine what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku push failing with build errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131261/heroku-push-failing-with-build-errors)

Comment: React requires you to upload the build folder instead of the entire directory. this was my problem